# Print Variable returned from API

Tags: php, api

I have a simple script as below:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8;'); 
    $file = file_get_contents("http://weather.justcode.us/api.php?city=Suzhou");
    print_r(json_decode($file));
?>
```

And it returns

```
stdClass Object
(
    [apiVersion] => 1.0
    [data] => stdClass Object
        (
            [location] => Suzhou, CHN
            [temperature] => 68
            [skytext] => Clear
            [humidity] => 60
            [wind] => 13
            [date] => 2013-05-04
            [day] => Saturday
        )

)
```

How do I print (for example) just data->location or just data->date? Oh, and apologies in advance if this is a simple question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8;'); 
$file = file_get_contents("http://weather.justcode.us/api.php?city=Suzhou");
$values= json_decode($file);
$data=$values->data;
echo $data->location;

?>
```

Output

```
   Suzhou, CHN
```

Here you can access any data like,

```
  $data->location,data->date etc
```

Answer (score 1):

`json_decode` just returns a simple object. Use `->` to access its properties.

```
echo $file->data->location;
echo $file->data->date;
```